# Why is this probability statement true?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I'm reading the proof to a martingale central limit theorem. In the statement of the theorem, we assume that $\eta^2$ is an almost surely (a.s.) finite random variable.

In case I, they wrote, "Suppose first that $\eta^2$ is a.s. bounded, so that for some $C (>1)$, $P(\eta^2 < C) = 1$." In case II, they wrote, "If $\eta^2$ is not a.s. bounded, then given $\epsilon > 0$, choose a continuity point $C$ of $\eta^2$ such that $P(\eta^2 > C) > \epsilon$". My confusion is about case II.

**How come if $\eta^2$ is not a.s. bounded, then given $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose a continuity point $C$ of $\eta^2$ such that $P(\eta^2 > C) > \epsilon$? How do we show this?**

Comment: How many points can there be where $\eta^2$ is *not* continuous?

Answer (score 2):

We can find $R$ such that $\mathbb P(\eta^2>R)\lt \varepsilon$ (this because the sequence of sets $(\{\eta^2>R\})_{R\in\mathbb N}$ is non-increasing and the intersection is a set of zero measure).

Hence for each $t\geqslant R$, $\mathbb P(\eta^2>t)\lt\varepsilon$. Since the cumulative distribution function of a random variable is non-increasing, it has only countably many discontinuity points. Since the interval $(R,+\infty)$ is uncountable, there exists a continuity point of the c.d.f. of $\eta^2$ in this interval.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Also, you caught the typo in the book; we have that $P(\eta^2 > C) < \epsilon$, not $P(\eta^2 > C) > \epsilon$. Anyway, did we ever need to use that fact that $\eta^2$ is not a.s. bounded in order to get that $P(\eta^2 > C) < \epsilon$? Or did we just need to use the fact that $\eta^2$ is a random variable?

Comment: You only need the fact that $\eta^2$ is a random variable (it would also work for a.s. bounded random variables).